# Find out which view is touching in multiple layouts in linearlayout in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to create layout dynamically using Java.

I have created 9 linear layouts dynamically as below:

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
    cpName = parser.getValue(e,"coverpage");    
    System.out.println("coverpage name :" + cpName);

    LinearLayout lbottomLayoutu1=new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    lbottomLayoutu1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1u1= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height/4);
    layoutParams1u1.weight=1.0f;    
    lbottomLayoutu1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1u1);
    lbottomLayoutu1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    lbottomLayoutu1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image);
    linearLayout.addView(lbottomLayoutu1);

    ImageView iv1=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width/4,height/4);
    iv1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.coverpage3);
    lbottomLayoutu1.addView(iv1);

    lbottomLayoutu1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Calling coverpage");
            String Url = WebUrl+cpName;
            System.out.println("web Url: " + Url);
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CurlActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Image Url",Url);
            in.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });
    setContentView(linearLayout);
}
```

I put a touch event for every layout. But if I touch any layout how can I know which layout is touching?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use custom listView (like here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507651/Customized-Android-ListView-with-Image-and-Text)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ids of each layout as

```
    obj.setId(i)
```

so that in your touch event you can identify it with

```
    int id=obj.getId()
```

and work accordingly!

Comment: i set id above the imageView and getting the id in setOnClickListener() method but where ever view i touching its giving last id value only.

Comment: if you have set id of the imageview,then the setonclick event should also be of the imageview.same in case of layouts.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the OnClickListener for the view, like you did...

```
lbottomLayoutu1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

... the parameter `View v` tells you which layout has been touched. You can then cast it to your expected layout, like:

```
LinearLayout clickedLayout = (LinearLayout) v;
```

This will be the layout that has been clicked.

If you want, however, know the index that you used in the loop, you have to overwrite your `LinearLayout` and give it a member that holds the index. Then you can cast it to your custom LinearLayout class and get the index. (If you need more help on this, let me know in the comments).